# How to pivot dataframe with new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

i want to pivot dataframe like below:

```
original_data = {
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'B': ['5', '6', '7', '8'],
    'C': ['9', '10', '11', '12']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
```

result:

```
   A  B   C
0  a  5   9
1  b  6  10
2  c  7  11
3  d  8  12
```

```
fixed_data = {
    'a': ['5', '9'],
    'b': ['6', '10'],
    'c': ['7', '11'],
    'd': ['8', '12'],
    'new': ['B', 'C']
}
```

result:

```
   a   b   c   d new
0  5   6   7   8   B
1  9  10  11  12   C
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
df.set_index('A').T.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis('new').reset_index()
```

or as @wjandrea states in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734844/how-to-pivot-dataframe-with-new-column/76734886?noredirect=1#comment135282863_76734886):

```
df.set_index('A').rename_axis(None).T.reset_index(names=['new'])
```

Output:

```
  new  a   b   c   d
0   B  5   6   7   8
1   C  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: I got basically the same thing but a bit shorter: `df.set_index('A').rename_axis(None).T.reset_index(names=['new'])`. By all means use it if you want.